# Excel marking row text to column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet

[image: Original Excel]

I want to mark the defects individually 
.For which I am currently creating column and marking  "X"  for the text present in column B

Expected sheet

[image: expected sheet]

Currently I am doing it manually any formula suggestion.
Tried find and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C2 use,

```
=if(isnumber(search(c$1, $b2)), "X", "")
```

Fill right and down.